# What do you call the noise(s) that block you from hearing?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

I am looking for a particular word to describe absurd noises which block your hearing.

Not so long ago, I was talking to a friend of mine in a public place and we were unable to hear each other well, due to the surrounding voices and noises.

Is there a word that fits this description?

Comment: Background noise

Comment: How would you differentiate "absurd" noise from ordinary background noise?

Comment: I strongly suspect "absurd" was not the intended word. Either that, or we have another case where the local dialect of English diverges from established usage.

Comment: The answer is "noise" or "loud noise" or "deafening noise" (though that has specific connotations).  Noise already means "unwanted sound"

Comment: This is a tricky question, as the average human can hear and understand conversation in spite of considerable noise.  For the noise to prevent aural comprehension it must be present in certain frequency bands and tempos, and this varies somewhat depending on the conditions (amount of echo in the room, etc).  Plus individuals vary in their abilities to decode speech, with the ability weakening as we age.  So it's really hard to characterize, in a few words, the sort of noise that prevents the comprehension of speech.

Answer (score 7):

***[Background noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_noise)***

> In acoustics and specifically in acoustical engineering, background noise or ambient noise is any sound other than the sound being monitored (primary sound). Background noise is a form of **noise pollution or interference.**
>
> Examples of background noises are environmental noises such as waves, traffic noise, alarms, people talking, bioacoustic noise from animals or birds and mechanical noise from devices such as refrigerators or air conditioning, power supplies or motors.

---

As you can see from the definition, you can call this block as *[interference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interference_%28communication%29)* also.

> In communications and electronics, especially in telecommunications, interference is anything which alters, modifies, or disrupts a signal as it travels along a channel between a source and a receiver

[Example](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interference):

> We had to put up with loud noise and constant interference from the neighbors.

Comment: Background noise usually signifies that its in the background, so it really isn't bothering anyone.  If it was that loud it would be in the foreground.  Interference doesn't make sense here too sense it has an alternative meaning with sound and it just confuses.

Answer (score 4):

**[Cacophony](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cacophony)**

> 1. harsh discordance of sound; dissonance: a cacophony of hoots, cackles, and wails.
> 2. a discordant and meaningless mixture of sounds: the cacophony produced by city traffic at midday.
> 3. Music. frequent use of discords of a harshness and relationship difficult to understand.

Comment: A high pitch laugh might be described as cacophony.  Not sure I would use that word on crowd noise.  This is where definition looks OK but usage tells us different.

Answer (score 3):

*Noise [pollution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise_pollution)* or *noise nuisance*.

> [noise pollution](http://www.princeton.edu/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Noise_pollution.html) is excessive, displeasing human, animal, or machine-created environmental noise that disrupts the activity or balance of human or animal life.

Also, consider *peripheral noise* and *clamor*.

> [clamor](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clamor): a loud continuous noise: city streets filled with clamor

Answer (score 3):

I'd say **deafening** noise, as it (almost) prevented you from hearing

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deafening

Answer (score 2):

I would simply say, "I can't hear with all of that [racket](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/racket) going on around us."

> confused clattering noise
>
> a loud annoying noise that continues for a long time

Comment: Along this same vein: ruckus, commotion

Answer (score 1):

Another term is "**white noise**"... although I think this implies more of a *uniform* background noise (like what is found on a airplane or if you turn on a fan) than a large group of people talking.

Answer (score 1):

"Noise" already means unwanted sound.  In other words, you need an adjective to describe an unwanted sound that stops your hearing.  And to that, I offer "**loud**".

> Noise means any unwanted sound. Noise is not necessarily random. 
>   *Sounds, particularly loud ones, that disturb people or make it difficult to hear wanted sounds, are **noise***.

Also http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/noise:

> 2 a any sound that is undesired or interferes with one's hearing of something

Answer (score 0):

Although it doesn't refer directly to noises that block  hearing, the term *cocktail party effect* is relevant.  [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cocktail_party_effect) defines it as

> the ability (or the difficulty) of focusing one's attention on a single auditory source in a jumble of noises

(See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_party_effect) for discussion of research on the topic.)  The noise at a cocktail party may be referred to as *chatter* or *cocktail chatter*.

Answer (score 0):

The noise you describe might be characterized as ***obfuscatory***, since it conceals or overshadows your friend's words.